# global name 'get_user_model' is not defined

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, nameerror

**NameError** at */project/reset_password_confirm/MTQ-4c8-65d880f1c28996091226/*

```
global name 'get_user_model' is not defined
Request Method: POST
Django Version: 1.9.1
Exception Type: NameError
Exception Value:    
global name 'get_user_model' is not defined
Exception Location: /root/django/studie/project/views.py in post, line 770
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.9
```

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

line 770:

```
    def post(self, request, uidb64=None, token=None, *arg, **kwargs):
    UserModel =  get_user_model()
    ....
```

Why does get_user_model() not work? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the import to your `views.py`.

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
```

Comment: I already tried. It says: ImportError: cannot import name get_user_model

Comment: EDIT: my fault! from django.contrib.auth.models import get_user_model doesn't obviously work. from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model does work! Thanks :)